# Any statistical distributions library for Java which is faster than Apache Commons?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I have written a complex simulation software in Java, in which I need to use a lot of statistical distributions (Gamma, Poission, and Exponential). So far, I have been using the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html) library for this, but the calls to Apache Commons are consuming a lot of runtime, which I found out by using a Java profiler (yourkit). The average runtime is > 4minutes, which is unacceptable for me.

Since I am trying to shorten my program's runtime, I was wondering if there is any better library which I might include/attach directly with my Java code?

I use the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

JDistlib—Java Statistical Distribution Library.[To find more, click here](http://jdistlib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks... trying to find a minimal example on how to use JDistlib, preferably in Eclipse. Could you please point to any such example?

Comment: Check this, http://www2.thu.edu.tw/~wenwei/examples.html

Comment: I already did, but it seems that link is about another Java software called javastat (found nothing on JDistlib)... looks like they are different?